# Is there anyway to debug typescript using the ember cli with vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ember.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I searched on stackoverflow and found this post:
[How to debug Javascript-Code produced and served by ember-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901546/how-to-debug-javascript-code-produced-and-served-by-ember-cli)

however, it was made in 2014 and I hope maybe some features were added or anything.

I am trying to place breakpoints in vscode in my typescript files. However, it doesn't seem to work at all, because the ember cli doesn't map ts to js files that it creates.

Answer (score 1):

To enable sourcemaps for TypeScript files in Ember, you must configure Babel to use inline sourcemaps. See: [Enabling Sourcemaps](https://ember-cli-typescript.com/docs/configuration#enabling-sourcemaps) in the ember-cli-typescript docs.